# Alpine linux create a apk-package

Tags: performance, shell, alpine-linux

The usual way to create an apk-file (alpine linux package manager format, not to be confused with androids apk) is to use abuild. However I need to create an apk from a directory with files. That is, without an aports recipe. That can be done this way:

```
tar --xattrs -f - -c * | abuild-tar --hash | gzip -9 > ../testpackage.data.tar.gz
du -b . | tail -n 1 | awk '{print \"size = \"$1}' >> .PKGINFO
tar -c .PKGINFO .pre-install .post-install .pre-deinstall .post-deinstall | abuild-tar --cut | gzip -9 > ../testpackage.control.tar.gz
abuild-sign ../testpackage.control.tar.gz
cat ../testpackage.control.tar.gz ../testpackage.data.tar.gz > testpackage.apk
```

The problem with this is that it's way too slow. I want to speed this up. Preferable with shell but in worst case I can write a C program for it.

How can the performance of this script be increased?

Comment: I am trying to create an .apk package this way (I am in the same situation as you, apprently...), however, when I tri to install such a package, I get an error:

apk add --allow-untrusted ./lua54-1.0.0.apk 
ERROR: ./lua54-1.0.0.apk: Not supported

Comment: Latest apk is getting pretty huge upgrades. Which apk version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you *really* need maximum compression `-9` (for `gzip`) adds quite a lot of extra processing for relatively little gain (depending slightly on your data), so try dropping it.

Adding the `-s` flag to your `du` will negate the need for the `tail` (probably won't make much difference)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pigz` instead of `gzip`to utilize multiple cores during compression.